# Key comparisons for Linq GroupBy using Default EqualityComparer

Tags: linq, group-by, iequatable

I'm trying to do a Linq GroupBy on some objects using an explicit key type. I'm not passing an `IEqualityComparer` to the GroupBy, so according to the docs:

> The default equality comparer `Default` is used to compare keys.

It explains the `EqualityComparer<T>.Default` property like this:

> The `Default` property checks whether
>   type `T` implements the
>   `System.IEquatable<T>` generic interface
>   and if so returns an
>   `EqualityComparer<T>` that uses that
>   implementation.

In the code below, I'm grouping an array of `Fred` objects. They have a key type called `FredKey`, which implements `IEquatable<FredKey>`.

That should be enough to make the grouping work, but the grouping is not working. In the last line below I should have 2 groups, but I don't, I just have 3 groups containing the 3 input items.

Why is the grouping not working?

```
class Fred
{
    public string A;
    public string B;
    public FredKey Key
    {
        get { return new FredKey() { A = this.A }; }
    }
}

class FredKey : IEquatable<FredKey>
{
    public string A;
    public bool Equals(FredKey other)
    {
        return A == other.A;
    }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var f = new Fred[]
        {
            new Fred {A = "hello", B = "frog"},
            new Fred {A = "jim", B = "jog"},
            new Fred {A = "hello", B = "bog"},
        };

        var groups = f.GroupBy(x => x.Key);
        Debug.Assert(groups.Count() == 2);  // <--- fails
    }
}
```

Answer (score 20, accepted):

From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms131187.aspx)

> If you implement IEquatable, you should also override the base class implementations of Object::Equals(Object) and GetHashCode() so that their behavior is consistent with that of the IEquatable::Equals  method. If you do override Object::Equals(Object), your overridden implementation is also called in calls to the static Equals(System.Object, System.Object)  method on your class. This ensures that all invocations of the Equals()  method return consistent results.

add this to FredKey and it should work

```
public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        return A.GetHashCode();
    }
```

Comment: That was it. Thanks. I found a good explanation here: http://www.codeproject.com/KB/dotnet/IEquatable.aspx

Comment: Does this mean that you should have *two* Equals methods in `FredKey`: one for `Equals(Object)` and one for `Equals(FredKey)`?

Answer (score 7):

Here is a complete example [with a Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/sFcRwW). Note: the example differs *slightly* from the question's example.

The following implementation of `IEquatable` can act as the `TKey` in [`GroupBy`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/bb534304(v=vs.100).aspx). Note that it includes both `GetHashCode` and `Equals`.

```
public class CustomKey : IEquatable<CustomKey>
{
    public string A { get; set; }
    public string B { get; set; }

    public bool Equals(CustomKey other)
    {
        return other.A == A && other.B == B;
    }

    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        return string.Format("{0}{1}", A, B).GetHashCode();
    }
}

public class Custom
{
    public string A { get; set; }
    public string B { get; set; }
    public string C { get; set; }
}

public static void Main()
{
    var c = new Custom[]
       {
           new Custom {A = "hello", B = "frog" },
           new Custom {A = "jim", B = "jog" },
           new Custom {A = "hello", B = "frog" },
       };

    var groups = c.GroupBy(x => new CustomKey { A = x.A, B = x.B } );
       Console.WriteLine(groups.Count() == 2);  
}
```